# I need to make the color of bottom navigation bar same as my bottom sheet dialog in dark mode. Is there a way to do it programatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, bottomsheetdialogfragment

There is a requirement to have bottom sheet dialog and bottom navigation bar as same color with buttons (e.g. back) should not get dim. I tried ways but not working correctly. Is there a way to extract the color from bottom sheet dialog and apply to navigation bar programatically?

Comment: Do not try to create a beautiful and integrated user interface in Android. Because Google and Android do not care about the user interface and it is very complicated and sloppy.